# Why is VSIX attempting to load random files as assemblies?

Tags: visual-studio, vsix

**In short**: When building a VSIX project In Visual Studio 2015, the build process is attempting to load random files (such as icons, .config files, .targets file) as if they were .Net assemblies.

I am attempting to build a VSIX project that includes a referenced project template and a embedded wizard assembly. I've done the exact same thing previously with success, following the steps described at [How to: Use Wizards with Project Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185301.aspx).

This time, however, when I attempt to build the VSIX project I get bizarre errors such as the following:

> Could not determine the FullName of the Assembly at "C:\Source\VSTS\Toolkits\v7\Web.Site\v7.2\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\csc.exe.config". Could not load file or assembly 'csc.exe.config' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Note, the compiler is trying to load a **config** file as if it were an assembly. In fact, I first got this error when it was attempting to load the *icon* file for the VSIX...as if it were an assembly. If I rename or remove the file in the error message and rebuild I just get the same error but with the next random not-an-assembly file that the compiler encounters.

Why is the compiler attempting to load random files as if they were assemblies? How can I make it stop so that I can actually build my VSIX project?

**More info**:

This error is thrown by the DetokenizeVsizManifestSource build step defined in Microsoft.VsSDK.targets:

```
<DetokenizeVsixManifestSource
  InputFile="@(SourceVsixManifest)"
  OutputFile="$(IntermediateVsixManifest)"
  ResolvedReferences="@(_VsixManifestResolvedReferences)">
  <Output TaskParameter="OutputFile" ItemName="FileWrites" />
</DetokenizeVsixManifestSource>
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am getting same error for app.config.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seems you can't add add an applciation to a VSIX. You need the project  to output a dll and attach that.
If you need to attach an application try to do so as File not as Project.